# Looking at this graph would you say there is no correlation between these two variables?

Tags: random-variables, correlation, visualization

I am trying to figure out if there is a correlation between Military Enlistment and the number of U.S. War Films Released between 1980-2021?

This is a graph I made in Tableau for data for the Department of Defense Total Enlistment between 1980-2021 and number of U.S. war films released. Looking at this graph I don't think there was a correlation between the two but wanted to double check. Is there no correlation or is there a negative correlation?

[image]

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The trouble is that the military enlistment has very little variability. It's basically two levels with a drop-off in the early 90s. With that little variation in one of the two variables, it's very difficult to determine whether there's a correlation on a graph like this. Try plotting number of films on the $x$-axis and military enrollment on the $y$-axis. My guess is it'll look pretty flat (i.e., little/no correlation), but you might be able to find a trend there.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Those are great suggestions! I'll try that.